# Use show_placeholder inside inclusion tag template in Django CMS

Tags: django-cms

I'm trying to create a portfolio overview page using Django CMS.

I have my detail pages already and they have a placeholder called `preview-img`. For my portfolio overview page, I need to loop over all detail pages and render that placeholder.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) tell me that an `inclusion tag` is the way to go. So I defined my tag (`show_portfolio`) in the `templatetags` directory such that it returns the pages:

```py
from django import template
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from django.template import RequestContext

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('portfolio_item.html', takes_context=True)
def show_portfolio(context, parent_slug):
    cms_pages = Page.objects.public()
    cms_pages = [
        page for page in cms_pages
        if page.parent_page and page.parent_page.get_slug() == parent_slug
    ]
    return {
        'cms_pages': cms_pages,
    }
```

It simply returns the page objects with a given parent page (via slug).

The template in which I now loop over the `cms_pages` is this (note the attempt to render each pages' `preview` `show_placeholder`):

[portfolio_item.html]

```
{% load cms_tags %}

<div class="row">
    {% for page in cms_pages %}
        ...
        {% show_placeholder "preview-img" page %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Running this, the server hits an uncaught `KeyError` (key: `request`) when trying to evaluate `show_placeholder`. I do not see the connection to what I'm doing. Where does the request come into play? Is it even possible to use `show_placeholder` inside the template of an `inclusion tag`?

Here's the trace for completeness:

Traceback:

```
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
  153.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py" in render_tag
  93.         rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
  153.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in render_tag
  443.             return toolbar.render_with_structure(context, nodelist)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/cms/toolbar/toolbar.py" in render_with_structure
  498.         rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  245.         return t.render(new_context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  203.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in _show_placeholder_by_id
  116.     request = context['request']

File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __getitem__
  87.         raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: Why do you have `takes_context=True` when you don't do anything with the context in `show_portfolio`? Maybe that's what is messing things up...

Comment: @PoByBolek a leftover from an experiment that I failed to remove before posting. Behavior is unchanged if I remove it, though. Also, cheers 8)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in my test setup by explicitly passing the request in the context for the inclusion tag:

```python
from django import template
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('portfolio_item.html', takes_context=True)
def show_portfolio(context, parent_slug):
    cms_pages = Page.objects.public()
    cms_pages = [
        page for page in cms_pages
        if page.parent_page and page.parent_page.get_slug() == parent_slug
    ]
    return {
        'request': context.request,
        'cms_pages': cms_pages,
    }
```

Comment: Will try this out later

Comment: If work ever bores you and you feel like spending more time on something other than your private server, feel free to check out my newest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392124/properly-mount-flask-app-at-location-using-nginx-reverse-proxy

/edit: Mentioning ppl seems to be broken